# What does 50va mean on a 480v/24v transformer

Tags: transformer

What does 50va mean on a 24 volt transformer.

Comment: notice that the answers correctly use "VA", not "va". Capitalization makes a difference for physical units!

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, it's VA, not 'va'.

50 VA means that it can supply 50 volt-amps.

At 24 V secondary that means it can supply a little over 2 A. (2 A x 24 V = 48 VA.)

Primary current will ideally be given by \$ I = \frac {VA}{V} = \frac {50}{480} = 0.104~A \$. Due to losses in the transformer the primary current will be, maybe, 10 to 20% higher than that at full load.

Answer (score 1):

It is voltampere, the unit for indicating apparent power.

VA  = Vac x Iac

50  = 24  x  ?

Iac = 2,083 A

Real power is indicated by watt (W). This is in electrical terms the real power that can be supplied by the device. The real power is less than the apparent power and is the part that actually does any work and dissipates heat. So the current available to you is less than Iac.

Comment: Minor point: SI units capitalise abbreviation named after a person and lower-case when spelled out. e.g., W for watt, V for volt, Hz for hertz, K for kelvin, etc.